# Array Runtime Error

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a simple program for school that's a simple String builder, I'm properly defining the array size, yet when I run the program, `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` is thrown. I initialize the variables in the constructor, name and classes. `name` is the student's name, `classes` is how many classes the student has each day. The size of my arrays is defined using `classes`. Here is my constructor and variables.

```
protected String name = "";
protected int classes;
private String schedule = "";
private String[] course = new String[classes];
private String[] room = new String[classes];
private int[] Period = new int[classes];

public StringBuilderHandler(String name, int classes) {
    this.name = name;
    this.classes = classes;
}
```

I'm using a for loop to set what String schedule will be.

```
private void setClass(int index) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    class[index] = scan.nextLine();
}

private void setPeriod(int index) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    period[index] = scan.nextInt();
}

public void setRoom(int index) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    room[index] = scan.nextLine();    
}

public void buildSchedule() {
    for (int i = 0; i < classes; i++) {
        System.out.println("What is your class?");
        setClass(i);
        System.out.println("What period is this class?");
        setPeriod(i);
        System.out.println("What room is this class?");
        setRoom(i);
        schedule = schedule +"Period "+period[i]+"\t"+course[i]+"\tRoom "+room[i]+"\n";
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't `class[index]` be `course[index]` in `setClass`?

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer since some good answers have already been posted.

Comment: @AVD: please read the homework tag wiki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your classes instance variable gets a default value of 0 since you have not initialized it. All your arrays are therefore getting initialized with a zero size. You are getting an exception because there is no index 0 since the arrays have zero size. You need to initialize the classes instance variable to a non zero positive value.

You may still get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if you try to insert more values into the array than its size. A quick solution would be to use an ArrayList instead of arrays.

Answer (score 3):

You *must* have to create objects (array) inside the constructor.

```
private String[] course;
private String[] room;
private int[] Period;

public StringBuilderHandler(String name, int classes) {
    this.name = name;
    this.classes = classes;
    this.course = new String[classes];
    this.room = new String[classes];
    this.Period = new int[classes]; 
}
```

Comment: This has made the code cleaner but there are still chances of an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if a value of 0 I'd passed to the constructor for the classes argument. What would be ideal is to use an ArrayList

Comment: @bot Agree! and of course more attention is needed with `arrays`.

Comment: Thank you, this totally slipped my mind and it's kind of embarrassing.
@bot Yeah it would, but my instructor's only permitting us to use specific methods.

Comment: Even if you use an arrays instead of an ArrayList, I feel my answer explained why you were getting the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException which was your question and not how you should initialize the arrays.

Answer (score 2):

you just need to define your class as:

```
protected String name = "";
protected int classes;
private String schedule = "";
private String[] course;
private String[] room;
private int[] Period;

public StringBuilderHandler(String name, int classes) {
    this.name = name;
    this.classes = classes;
    this.course = new String[classes];
    this.room = new String[classes];
    this.Period = new int[classes]; 
}
```

For sure it will work. You were using classes variable without initializing it because its initializing at run time. You just need to initialize array in constructor when classes has a value.

Comment: How does that solve te problem? What if I pass a 0 value to the constructor for the classes argument? Changing the code structure is not going to implicitly make the exception go away. This does not answer the question.

Comment: @bot you are right. But this issue solved by the programmer only because he have to make sure that 0 must not pass in method. These type of issues handle by the programmer.

Comment: You are missing the point. The thing with arrays us that they have a fixed size. You can't add elements beyond a particular index or you will get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. What do you do then to add more elements to an already full array? You either create a new array double its size and copy its content to this array or you simply use an ArrayList. I hope you understand why your answer doesn't solve the problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialised that variable classes anywhere?

You've initialised all the arrays of size classes, but classes doesn't appear to be initialised.

Comment: In the main class I use methods in the Scanner class to initialize name and classes.